# Delete comments of DOM for *ngFor and *ngIf in Angularjs2

Tags: angular

Is it possible to remove comments that makes the DOM "*ngIf" or "*ngFor" AngularJS2 when there isn't an element to render?

Maybe it's possible to set this up somewhere and not know. I would have the DOM as clean as possible and not see comments like this:

```
<!--template bindings={}-->
```

Comment: no...they are there for a reason. Comments have a `nodeType` and can be read in the DOM

Comment: it's just because I'm building a pretty gigantic application and I have to read the code many times, and I would only see my own comments, nothing more ...

Comment: well you can't do it. Angular uses them internally

Comment: Possible "work arounds": 1. Read the code in an IDE, 2. Debug in Chrome, so you could easily jump to an Element an view the source (Mac: alt + cmd + c), 3. Export the body code and strip the comments out ( `const bodyString = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<!--template bindings=\{\}-->/gi, '');`) and read it in an editor like sublime - hopefully something is for anyone any better option

Answer (score 2):

They are placeholders so Angular knows where to render elements. 
For example when the collection you refer to is empty and then add data Angular needs to know where to render the first template item.

Comment: Ok, so I assume is impossible to eliminate ... Well, thank you for the explanation

Comment: Probably nobody in the angular development could say, why can't these data exist in the Javascript. Trashing the DOM is total normal in the angular development.

Comment: Because Angular needs some anchors for it's binding to know where to render elements.

Comment: Angular2 should improve this area. Must be a way to remove all comments from DOM in angular2, this cause performance issues. Google page speed complain about "Avoid an excessive DOM size" large DOM will increase memory usage

Comment: Even enabling "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None," angular2 and above still rendering comments like this <!---->