# unable to remove empty tag using angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here I am having a issue  below is my json data

```
 data = {
  "required": false,
  "name": "data",
  "details": [
    {
      "name": "type",
      "details": {
        "visible": false,

      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Creation",
      "details": {

        "visible":true,

      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Creation",
      "details": {

        "visible": false,

      }
    },

    {
      "name": "Modification",
      "details": {

        "visible": true,

      }
    }

  ]
}
```

.html code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of data.details">
  <ul>
  <li *ngIf="x.details.visible">             
      {{x.name}}
  </li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

The issue here is even though I condition is true here it is creating empty tags by this my html style is getting disturbed and getting unwanted spaces

in the console it showed me like this

```
<ul _ngcontent-c76=""><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></ul>

<ul _ngcontent-c76=""><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><li _ngcontent-c76=""> Creation </li></ul>

<ul _ngcontent-c76=""><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></ul>

<ul _ngcontent-c76=""><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><li _ngcontent-c76=""> Modification</li></ul>
```

How can I remove that empty spaces.

Below is my stack blitz URL.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yw2zy5

Comment: Move the *ngIf to the ul tag.

Comment: use the `ngIf` condition in your `ul`. BTW you want so many `uls`? or one ul and many `lis`?

Comment: @AshishRanjan the uls & lis are generated depending on my data if the visible is false it shouldnt display but here if it is false then it is displaying empty tags

Comment: @techie look at this post [Delete comments of DOM for *ngFor and *ngIf in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35206239/9775003)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your template to following

```html
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let x of data.details">
    <li *ngIf="x.details.visible">
      {{x.name}}
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

You would not want to have bunch of `ul` with single `li` elements. What the code above will do is to create a single `ul` and add some `li` elements within if `x.details.visible` condition is met

Answer (score 2):

Issues with your implementation:

1. You have `*ngFor` on the `ul` instead of the `li`. That is making the `ul` getting repeated on the DOM and thus breaking your style.
2. You should be using the `ng-container` as a parent of the `li` instead of using it as a parent to the `ul`. That way, you will be able to add the `*ngIf` condition on the `li` while using `*ngFor` on the `ng-container`.

Give this a try:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let x of data.details">
        <li *ngIf="x.details.visible">
            {{x.name}}
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-container-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.